# WPF: Show and hide user controls after user interaction

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-interface, user-controls

I have got the following window which contains my user controls in the upper area (depending on the state of the process) and a button. After click at the button one user control will be hidden and another will be shown. By the change from the first to the second control the window is frozen until the second control is finished with the tasks.

The second control contains a ListView which logs the steps. I want to see this logging directly during the process. But I can only see it when all is finish. How is it possible to refresh the window before the second control starts with it work?

A code line like

```
Me.UpdateLayout()
```

doesn't work ...

The whole program shalls be an update tool with three screens (1. settings, 2. logging of the update process, 3. finish dialog). Therefore I need to know the single steps of the logging directly after done.

My current XAML is the following:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:SiS.Controls="clr-namespace:SiSConverter"
    Title="Konvertierung von SiS-Anwendungen"
    Height="400" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="50px" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <SiS.Controls:Settings x:Name="ucSettings" />
        <SiS.Controls:Upgrade x:Name="ucUpgrade" />
        <SiS.Controls:Finish x:Name="ucFinish" />

        <Button Name="btnContinue" Width="100px" Height="30px" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the corresponding code behind:

```
Class MainWindow 

    Private _Step As Integer = -1
    Private Property [Step] As Integer
        Get
            Return _Step
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _Step = value

            Me.ucSettings.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
            Me.ucUpgrade.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
            Me.ucFinish.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
            Me.btnContinue.Content = "Weiter"

            Select Case _Step
                Case 0
                    Me.ucSettings.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
                Case 1
                    Me.ucUpgrade.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
                Case 2
                    Me.ucFinish.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
                    Me.btnContinue.Content = "Beenden"
                Case Else
            End Select

            Me.UpdateLayout() 'doesn't work
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub MainWindow_Initialized(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Initialized
        Me.Step = 0

        For Each Item As System.IO.FileInfo In New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("Converters").GetFiles()
            Dim oConverter As ISiSConverter = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(Item.FullName).CreateInstance("Upgrade.Main", True)
            Me.ucSettings.Converters.Add(oConverter)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnContinue_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnContinue.Click
        Select Case Me.Step
            Case 0 'Einstellungen
                Me.Step += 1

                Me.btnContinue.IsEnabled = False

                Me.ucSettings.Converters.FindAll(Function(item) item.DoUpgrade).ForEach(Sub(item) item.Upgrade())

                Me.btnContinue.IsEnabled = True
            Case 1 'Upgrade
                Me.Step += 1
            Case 2 'Abschluss
                Me.Close()
            Case Else
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for any response.

**Edit:**
The program consists of three steps. In the first step will be configured what is to do.

[image: Step 1: configure]

With click on the bottom right button shall be done something for each marked item (green button, red will be ignored) which is shown by the list of the second step.

[image: Step 2: logging]

If step 2 is done the finish Screen is shown and the program can be closed (this screen is still to design).

[image: Step 3: finish]

In WinForms and ASP.NET I show and hide user controls also in the way I did this time (maybe also this wasn't before a good implementation). It would be nice if there is in WPF a better possibility.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but your code is a mess (no offense). You must not manipulate UI elements' properties in code in WPF. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to implement it in WPF.

Comment: I will post the screenshots tomorrow if I am back at office.

Comment: Screenshots are added.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is your UI thread which is the only one that can update the elements shown by your View / Window is too busy running your

```
Me.ucSettings.Converters.FindAll(Function(item) item.DoUpgrade).ForEach(Sub(item) item.Upgrade())
```

^^ function and hence cannot update the view / render elements until it's done.

A "cheat" kind of to explicitly show this (Just use this as information, don't use it in your code)

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                                   Sub()
                                                     Me.ucSettings.Converters.FindAll(Function(item) item.DoUpgrade).ForEach(Sub(item) item.Upgrade())
                                                   End Sub)
```

^^ That will show your new `UserControl` when the button is clicked. You still however have the issue of un-responsive UI.

You need to look at offloading work from the main thread by using things like [BackgroundWorkers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for what your doing from code-behind to keep the UI responsive and then whenever you need to update a UI control Notify the UI thread accordingly.